# Can a cold gas be considered as ideal at a very high speed?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, ideal-gas, atmospheric-science, air

Considering a plane flying in the atmosphere, my book uses the perfect gas law $pV=n\bar RT$. Yet, as the plane itself is taken as the reference, the air ($T=-50°C$) has a speed of $800 \ \mathrm{km/h}$.

I know that for low temperatures, the perfect gas law **does not work** and must be replaced by the [Soave-Redlich-Kwong](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/png520/m10_p5.html) (or just Redlich-Kwong) law. But here the situation is particular since the speed is very high.

Is their a way that $pV = n\bar R T$ could work in this context, or is my book totally wrong ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the law of corresponding states?

Comment: @ChetMiller unfortunately no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Moran et al, Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics, the "equivalent" critical properties of air are 133 K and 37.7 bars. The atmospheric temperature is -50 C at about 10 km, and the atmospheric pressure at this altitude is on the order of about 0.265 bars.  So the reduced temperature is 223/133 = 1.68 and the reduced pressure is 0.265/37.7 = 0.0070. According to the graph in Moran et al of real gas compressibility factor Z as a function of reduced temperature and pressure, at this reduced temperature and pressure, the compressibility factor for air is indistinguishable from 1.0.  Thus, ideal gas behavior is very closely approximated under these conditions.